# Javascript - Trying to use to log into a system

Tags: cypress

I am currently trying to use Cypress as an automation tool but it keeps failing at the start with the login.

I keep getting this message:

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element:
>   '#ctl00_mainContentArea_Login1_lv_lg_userName', but never found it.

I have added a login details as a json file and made the 'Login' with a direct url but still getting this error.

Here is the part of the code that keep failing but I can't figure where the error lies:

```
cy.get('#ctl00_mainContentArea_Login1_lv_lg_userName').type(this.login.username)
cy.get('#ctl00_mainContentArea_Login1_lv_lg_password').type(this.login.password)
cy.get('#ctl00_mainContentArea_Login1_lv_lg_LoginButton').click()
cy.url().should('contain','System/Dashboard.aspx')
```

Have i missed something in this part of the code??

Comment: Are you sure that you have an element with the id `ctl00_mainContentArea_Login1_lv_lg_userName`?

Comment: I am sure I do but I will redo the work and make sure. Thank you

Comment: You can try to test it, like, press F12 on Chrome and on the Console tab, write: `document.getElementById('ctl00_mainContentArea_Login1_lv_lg_userName')` and see if you have a result.